# create-react-app ; aborting installation while creating react app in windows 11 after installing node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I installed node js and create-react-app in my system and while performing the command to create the startup react project, i performed, `npx create-react-app <projectname>` command. But it failed all the time and i don't know how to proceed with this and i tried some of the already available solutions and nothing worked and i don't know how to proceed with this. I have attached the screenshot of the error. Have a look at it and help me with the solution.
[create-react-app_click_here_to_see_my_terminal_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU8MY.jpg)
Thanks in advance !!!